# Smartgwt - Disable formitem showing red cross image on IE

Tags: smartgwt

I am using smartgwt 2.2 for creating a form.

My problem is, when i disable FormItem (SpinnerItem) then disabled SpinnerItem is showing red cross image on IE but there is no problem in firefox.

Can anybody give me an idea why this is happening?

Comment: Did you compile for both IE and FF?

Comment: I created project in Springsource tool suite, then i compile project and then i did run as web application.After getting url on console, i did copy that url and use it in ie browser

Comment: for discussion and workarounds see http://forums.smartclient.com/showthread.php?t=6514

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running it in quirks mode? (removing the doctype declaration in your welcome html file). This solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the doctype from your main GWT host page